# use-package: Can :after be used instead of with-eval-after-load?

Tags: use-package, eval-after-load

If my `:config` section is entirely wrapped in `with-eval-after-load`, is that equivalent to simply specifying an `:after` directive? That is, can I replace this:

```
(use-package company-tern
  :config
  (with-eval-after-load 'company
    (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern)))
```

with this

```
(use-package company-tern
  :after company
  :config
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern))
```

Am I correct in my understanding that if there is other configuration that *isn't* inside of the `with-eval-after-load` then it wouldn't be useful to replace it with an `:after` directive since that would defer the loading of the *entire* package just for the subset of the configuration that depends on the feature?

I should note, in the above situation it seems simple enough to just nest `company-tern`'s use-package under `company`'s `:config` section, since they're logically related. However, my question is for the more general case where the "dependency" doesn't necessarily have a logical connection, or when there is more than one "dependency."

Comment: From what I understand of use-package's semantics, an alternative (cleaner?) possibility would be to put this `(add-to-list ...)` line in `company`'s `:config`. And if you want to defer the loading of the entire `company-tern` package, you could put `(use-package company-tern :config (add-to-list...))` in `company`'s `:config`.

Comment: Thank you for responding @T.Verron! I actually had a larger post/question and I split it up at the request of another user. I forgot to migrate over to this one the fact that I wanted to find a way to avoid nesting `use-package` inside of the `:config`. The reason for this doesn't apply to the example I gave, but consider other situations where there is no real logical connection other than using e.g. a function of another package, or when there is more than one such "dependencies," it wouldn't make sense to nest the package under more than one package's `:config` section after all.

Comment: Nesting use-packages is not a proper way to handle dependencies indeed. But for situations where the second package provides additional configuration to the first one, it kinda makes sense. Someone wrote blog posts on managing a configuration using use-package (maybe it was the author of the package himself), and he made extensive use of that, for example encapsulating his configuration into "personal" packages.

Comment: I agree completely. I'm already doing this for example with evil-related plugins, nesting them under evil's `:config`. I'm looking for approaches to situations where there isn't really a logical connection. I will clarify my question for other readers. By the way, if you find and link me those posts I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Here are a couple : http://www.lunaryorn.com/2015/01/06/my-emacs-configuration-with-use-package.html http://sachachua.com/blog/2014/12/emacs-configuration-use-package/ (the second contains a link to a video demonstration by the author of use-package, but I didn't watch it) Sadly, I cannot find the one post that I had in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I believe those are equivalent.  If there's additional configuration outside of `with-eval-after-load`, then switching to use `:after` should be semantically equivalent to moving them inside the `with-eval-after-load` form and so may change when they are executed.  Whether this is a problem or not will depend on the exact configuration details.

Now, I don't know the exact details of how things are implemented, so it's possible that there's some very subtle timing issue, but at least your intuition seems to match mine here.

Comment: It's good to have a second opinion. Thanks!